# How can I block the continuous vowels(aeiou) in a string?

Tags: regex

How can I block the use of continuous vowels in a string and allow the use of only one hyphen(-)? Right now it allows as many hyphens the user enters. It should not allow any other special character other than a hyphen.

I have used `/^((?!aeiou)[a-zA-z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\-])*$/,`. It should not allow continuous vowels even if it's in upper case (AEIOU) and also in both upper and lower case in continuous form like AeiOU, aEIou etc. Only continuous vowels are restricted so 'aouie' and 'iouae' is pemitted.

Comment: your code is allowing more than one hyphens also when I am entering continuous vowels in these(aEIOU, AEIOU,aeIOU) forms it is accepting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
/^(?!.*-.*-)((?![Aa][Ee][Ii][Oo][Uu])[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\-])*$/
```

`(?!.*-.*-)` means that the begin of the string must not be followed by 2 hypens in any position.

See https://regex101.com/r/vrpqv9/1

Comment: It's perfect, I think the first one was also doing the trick just with one small modification but the 2nd one is spot on. Thank you

Comment: @Kumar You may consider to upvote and/or accept the answer

Comment: Upvoting permission is granted once a user gets 15 rep points.

Comment: I did both @horcrux